# How to round to the next multiple in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math

I'm looking for a JavaScript function which will round to the next multiple:

```
function arrondiSuperieur($nombre, $arrondi) {
    return ceil($nombre / $arrondi) * $arrondi;
}

echo arrondiSuperieur(6, 5); //display 10
echo arrondiSuperieur(16, 7); //display 21
```

Have you an idea?

Comment: 23 is a prime number... did you mean 21?

Comment: Why do you not use the function you have?
btw: ceil(16/7)*7 = ceil(1,28..) * 7 = 2 * 7 = 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translated PHP to JS:

```
function arrondiSuperieur(nombre, arrondi) {
    return Math.ceil(nombre / arrondi) * arrondi;
}

alert(arrondiSuperieur(6, 5)); //display 10
alert(arrondiSuperieur(16, 7)); //display 21
```

`alert` shows a dialog with the result. You can also use `document.write` if the script is directly run on load within the `<body>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want you function to do this:

```
function arrondiSuperieur($nombre, $arrondi) {
    return floor($nombre / $arrondi) * $arrondi + $arrondi;
}
```

This will round up to the closest number that is divisible by the second parameter in the function.